# changing margin-top affects others

Tags: css, html, margin

When I increase or decrease `margin-top` of `#nav` it affects `#header`, but when increasing `margin-top` of `#header` it doesn't affect `#nav`.

How to correct this to when I change whether nav or header it shouldnt affect other?

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#header {
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#header h1 {
  float: left;
}

#nav {
  width: 900px;
  ;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 34px;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>rrrr</h1>

</div>

<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sss</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">www</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">fff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ttt</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because nav is inside the header element so increasing the margin will change the height of header aswell

Comment: @Manjunath nav isn't inside the header but there is a margin-collapsing issue

Comment: ah! I did not notice the closing div. My bad ':)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a [margin-collapsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) issue. Since you made the `header` to be a float element, the `#nav` become the first in-flow element thus its margin will collapse with body margin.

> top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child

So when you increase the margin of the nav you increase the collapsed margin which is the margin of the body and you push all the content down including the `#header`.

To fix this you need to avoid the margin collapsing by adding (for example) a `padding-top` to the `body`.

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#header {
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#header h1 {
  float: left;
}

#nav {
  width: 900px;
  ;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  animation: ani1 2s;
  margin-top: 34px;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>rrrr</h1>
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sss</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">www</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">fff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ttt</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```